# How can I upload iOS app in my clients apple id

Tags: codenameone

I've built an iOS app using cn1 using netbeans (send to iOS appstore build).I've successfully tested it in debug mode. I've used iOS certificate wizard through codenameone setting. What happened is that it creates all required certificates including app ids identifers in my appleid and I can get provisioning profile and cert files from project properties. The problem for me is how can I use these certificates to upload an app in appstore of my clients appleId. Since I'd built the app using my itune and apple id, its confusing to upload the app in the appstore using clients apple id.

P.S I've also tried creating identifiers and provisioning profile in clients apple id too using x code. But while uploading ipa file through application loader, it gives invalid provisioning profile error ("This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with team id xxxxxx.")

However, while downloading the provisioning profile of the clients apple id and attaching it in the project through project properties, it gives built error:

```
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
Process return code is 0
Provisioning profile length: 7535
The provided provisioning profile and certificate do not match.  
Please ensure that the provisioning profile you provide was generated using 
the certificate that you provide.
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to your clients itunes account using the certificate wizard on his account is probably the best approach.

You need to make sure you replaced all 4 files, both provisioning versions and both certificates. If you changed the package/app id to match your client domain you need to look at this article which goes into more details on that https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deploy-same-mobile-app-template-multiple-times.html